# Can I brackets for events of jQuery?

Tags: jquery

A month ago I discovered a way to write jQuery events, like “AddClass” or “each”. This way is using brackets instead of a dot and the name of the event.

**An example:**

This is the usual code: `$('#myID').hide('slow');`

This is the brackets way: `$('#myID')['hide']('slow');`

I'm so amazed because I've never seen this before and I like write code different from others. But... I searched the Internet about this way of writing jQuery events, can't see anything about it.

Can anybody help me with this? Is this form recommendable to use? Does it have any disadvantages that I need to know of?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation

Comment: _"and I like write code different from others"_ - No, don't deliberately try to be different, write code that is reasonably standard so that it is easy to maintain. By the way, what you are calling "jQuery _events_" are really jQuery _methods._ This "brackets instead of a dot" concept applies to _all_ JavaScript object properties and methods, not just to jQuery methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same for any object property, you can access it as

```
obj['pname']
```

or

```
obj.pname
```

And the function `hide` is a property of the `$('#myID')` object, which means you can get this property as well using

```
$('#myID')['hide']
```

than using

```
$('#myID').hide
```

This kind of notation is useful when you want to be concise and have to call a function depending on some variable :

```
queue[priority?'unshift':'push']({src:src, callback:callback});
```

See [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) from the MDN for more details.

Comment: That was a very interesting example. TIL.

Comment: Actually, I didn't know if I could use this trick. The +1 was for that. :D

Answer (score 1):

Javascript objects can be accessed in two ways.

1. Conventional

   `obj.param1.param2`
2. As an associative array

   `obj['param1']['param2']`

Now, this works even for these cases

```
obj.func = function() { //achieve something, or not. }

obj['func'] = function() {//achieve something. }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the same, so yes you could use braket.

I personnaly hate using bracket and found no advantages except doing code like that :

```
function hideOrShow(show){
     //Show represant a var true or false
     $('div')[show ? 'show' : 'hide']();
}
```

wich is shorter than

```
function hideOrShow(show){
    if(show) $('div')show();
    else $('div')hide();
}
```

Using `.something()` is much more conventionnal and in my opinion, easier to read.

Comment: I know `hideOrShow()` was just an example, but `$('div').toggle(show);` is even shorter...

Comment: Don't worry, i know that, just a fast example.